# "Puesto que" + modo verbal

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

No sé si lo que pienso es correcto.

> En el momento siguiente prefirió quedarse en silencio **puesto que la
>   situación hubiera resultado rara**.

La gramática española dice que después de "puesto que" se utiliza el indicativo porque indica una causa con certeza. ¿Se puede decir que en este caso se trata de la alternancia entre el condicional compuesto y el pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo?

Gracias.

Comment: Yo habría dicho _habría resultado rara_, así que sí, creo que se trata de esa alternancia.

Comment: Yo pondría *habría resultado rara;* esto activa el subjuntivo en una clásula escondida de la siguiente forma: *(...)puesto que la situación habría resultado rara.* (**Si es que no se hubiese quedado en silencio.**)

Comment: @Ustanak creo que tienes razón: podría ser simplemente una sustitución directa por el condicional.  No es nada infrecuente que alguien diga *lo que diera por…* (en vez de *lo que daría por…*) además de otros ejemplos obvious de *quisiera* (por *querría*).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - ¿Podría ser equivalente a "En el momento siguiente prefirió quedarse en silencio puesto que la situación podría haber resultado rara"?  ¿Y que "hubiera" = "podría haber" (más o menos)?

Comment: @aparente001 pues sí, podría ser otra opción.

Comment: @Aurora Si bien la oración es algo extraña, creo que es gramatical tanto con "hubiera resultado rara" como con "habría resultado rara". La única interpretación que se me ocurre es que la situación hubiera resultado rara **si él no se hubiera quedado en silencio**, o sea, hay una condicional tácita. El contexto podría ser que nadie esperaba o preveía que él hablara de modo que, si lo hubiera hecho, se hubiera/habría generado una situación extraña. "puesto que" explica por qué prefirió quedarse en silencio: si no lo hubiera hecho, algo desagradable habría ocurrido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que hace poco respondí [otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21870/in-spanish-what-are-some-valid-cases-of-using-subjunctive-conjugation-without) que también tocaba este tema, aprovecho el material recopilado para responder esta.

Como bien apuntáis en los comentarios, el uso del subjuntivo en el ejemplo dado es, a todas luces, una sustitución del condicional.
Sobre la alternancia entre las construcciones *HABRÍA ...* y *HUBIERA ...*, la [*Nueva Gramática*](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi) dice (la negrita es mía):

> **[24.2q](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wGUoHswJNjZJXYJy)** El PRETÉRITO PLUSCUAMPERFECTO DE SUBJUNTIVO (HUBIERA o HUBIESE CANTADO) neutraliza dos tiempos del indicativo, como se explicó en el § 24.1a: el pretérito pluscuamperfecto **y el condicional compuesto**. (...) Los usos de HUBIERA o HUBIESE CANTADO se dividen en dos grupos. En el primero, esta forma no alterna con HABRÍA CANTADO, sino que aparece inducida por algún elemento gramatical (...) **En el segundo se produce una alternancia libre**, como en *Me {habría ~ hubiera} gustado trabajar con él*.

En los puntos siguientes explica los distintos casos y da multitud de ejemplos de la alternancia, cuándo aplica y cuándo no. Recomiendo la lectura de **[24.2s](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wGUoHswJNjZJXYJy)**, **[24.2t](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wMQNmaWBXkVJZlPv)** y **[24.2u](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wMQNmaWBXkVJZlPv)**; por mi parte me limitaré a decir que el uso que planteas es válido y aceptado tanto en el español americano como en el europeo.

Por completar, en **[24.2x](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=puUokAgJIzqpPDLC)** se dan un par de ejemplos que cuadran exactamente con los expuestos en la pregunta:

> **24.2x** En el § 23.15o se explica que el contenido que aportan las prótasis condicionales queda tácito en un gran número de contextos. El marco o el ámbito irreal que aportan esos segmentos no se expresa en tales casos, pero está presente en la conciencia lingüística de los hablantes:
>
> > *No subí a la noria porque me hubiera mareado* [se entiende '... de haber subido']); *Es mejor que no hayas visto la película. Te hubiera decepcionado* [se entiende '... de haberla visto'].

Resumiendo: sí, la construcción es correcta.